# NGX pagination search filter is not working after page change in angular

Tags: angular, pagination, angular13

This is search filter directives

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;
  
    return items.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key => {
        return String(item[key]).toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
      });
    });
   }
}
```

Below is the HTML code with array table

```
<input type="search" class="col-sm-3.1 m_left16 " id="searchAll" [(ngModel)]="searchAllDataBenchmark"
                                        placeholder="Search by keywords" autocomplete="off">

<tr *ngFor="let i of userArray2 | filter: searchAllDataBenchmark | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p } ">


<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

It's working properly when stay in 1st page in the pagination search filter is working. But when click the send page and search any table data it's not working and data table is not filtering. Data table array is showing blank.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the total items each time you change the page, So add this to your code and it should work.

paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p, , totalItems: userArray2.length } "

I solved this issue this way :D